# Morphia Interface for List of enum does not work (unmarshalling)

Tags: morphia

I have the following interface

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "className")
public interface InfoChartInformation {
    public String name();
}
```

And the following implementation (enum):

```
public class InfoChartSummary {    
    public static enum Immobilien implements InfoChartInformation {
        CITY, CONSTRUCTION_DATE;
    }
    public static enum Cars implements InfoChartInformation {
        POWER, MILEAGE;
    }
}
```

Then I use all of It in the following entity:

```
@Entity(noClassnameStored = true)
@Converters(InfoChartInformationMorphiaConverter.class)
public class TestEntity{
    @Id
    public ObjectId id;
    @Embedded
    public List<InfoChartInformation> order;
}
```

Jackson, in order to detect the type on the unmarshalling time, will add to every enum on the list the className.

I thought morphia would do the same, but there's no field className in the List of enum **and the unmarshalling cannot be done correctly**: `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.mongodb
.DBObject`

I guess the correct behavior should be to save all the enum route (package+name), not only the enum name. At least in that way the unmarshalling could be performed. There's a way morphia supports that by default or I need to create my own converter ([similar to this](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/blob/master/morphia/src/main/java/org/mongodb/morphia/converters/EnumConverter.java)) ?

Answer (score 1):

I tried creating a Custom Converter:

```
public class InfoChartInformationMorphiaConverter extends TypeConverter{
    public InfoChartInformationMorphiaConverter() {
        super(InfoChartInformation.class);
    }
    @Override
    public Object decode(Class targetClass, Object fromDBObject, MappedField optionalExtraInfo) {
        if (fromDBObject == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String clazz = fromDBObject.toString().substring(0, fromDBObject.toString().lastIndexOf("."));
        String value = fromDBObject.toString().substring(fromDBObject.toString().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        try {
            return Enum.valueOf((Class)Class.forName(clazz), value);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public Object encode(final Object value, final MappedField optionalExtraInfo) {
        return value.getClass().getName() + "." + ((InfoChartInformation) value).name();
    }
}
```

Then, I added the converter information to morphia `morphia.getMapper().getConverters().addConverter(new InfoChartInformationMorphiaConverter());`.

However, when serializing (or marshalling) the object to save it into the database, **the custom converter is ignored and the Enum is saved using the default Morphia converter** (only the enum name).

If I use in the `TestEntity` class only an attribute `InfoChartInformation;` instead of the `List<>InfoChartInformation>`, my customer converter will work. However I need support for List

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
public class InfoChartInformationMorphiaConverter extends TypeConverter implements SimpleValueConverter
```

It is a marker interface required to make your Convertor work.